# Navigation outside of component in react-router

Tags: react-router

Is this outdated? https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/95094769caca201b8e9afe68ff3d6cb4ff280fac/docs/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

I can't seem to get it working.
I'm exporting the history object like this:

```
export const history = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory')();
```

And then I'm using it like so:

```
history.push('/home');
```

But the page doesn't change, only the URL changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality still works fine and the current docs still have it [in master](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

Notice the extra `()` at the end of the require in your code.  That's a function call which returns a new history object instance.

In that doc they do the function call once in history.js and export the instance.  They then require history.js and used that instance for both the router and outside of the router.

Comment: Yes, you are right I also noticed that however I also had another problem where I wasn't calling the callback on an onEnter hook in the routes. Thanks for taking the time to respond.